# Get a mantis bug traker issue

Tags: spring-boot, rest, api, mantis

I am currently trying to get a Mantis issue through the Rest Api using spring boot but I don't know how i call the API in my code.
If someone can share a code in this topic, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Do you have any reference to the API you are mentioning? Please describe in more detail the application that should call the API.

Comment: yup this is the documentation of the API: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/29959/mantis-bug-tracker-rest-api/7Lt6zkP?version=latest#6ee0caac-fc5d-8aa5-3df0-57b999274e95  . The application it's just a webservice to get the issues from mantis